# What kind of sensor could detect the valve of a rotating soccer/rugby ball?

Tags: arduino, sensor, detection

I am trying to design a device that will detect the air pump valve of a ball and then rotate it to a home position. It will most likely be controlled by an Arduino.

I am a mechanical engineer and have no idea about sensors. This is for a college project so I am looking for a reasonably inexpensive solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A camera could do it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or do you want us to waste time making the obvious suggestions and listen to your objections  why don't want to try them? Too broad as it stands, VTC

Comment: I doubt an Arduino is fast enough for this.

Comment: Is modifiying the ball (e.g. by applying markers or black lines) acceptable?

Comment: Does the valve have metal parts?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done using machine vision.  Have a camera look at a section of the ball at this "home position".  Rotate the ball in a pattern so that every part of the ball is exposed to the camera each time thru the pattern.  At regular intervals, the picture is examined by software, and a attempt is made to find the valve.  If the valve is not seen, continue the pattern.  If the valve is seen, then stop the pattern and move the ball to position the valve as desired.